# Optimizing large query to use less JOINs, count distinct involved

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Well on Google BigQuery, we have a report with around 10 columns like:

```
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
|     uniquesent | uniquedelivered | uniquebounced | uniqueopens |
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
```

we have a longer query which uses lots of joins to compute these values, roughly the large query is organized this way:

```
select
    ...report_columns...,
   sent.uniquesent,
   delivered.uniquedelivered,
from [main table]
left join (
  select 
    language,
    exact_count_distinct(e.user_id) as uniquesent
   from emailevent e
    where country=1 and event='sent'
   group by 1
) as sent
left join (
  select 
    language,
    exact_count_distinct(e.user_id) as uniquedelivered
   from emailevent e
    where country=1 and event='delivered'
   group by 1
) as delivered
```

and this list of `JOINs` goes in the same style for other 10 similar items. Also imagine this query with group by day/week/month sections and it's get very complicated even to read. We also get error messages for some of them: Resource exceeded.

We would like to rewrite and optimize the queries to return the same numbers but be much more efficient. Let me know if you have additional questions, but mainly we want to eliminate joins somehow and make it compact and perform better.

We already applied some compacting to our queries with this syntax:

```
sum(if(p.country_id=1 AND event = "userblocked" AND JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(e.meta,'$.reason') contains 'drop_status',1,0)) as bounced,
sum(if(p.country_id=1 AND event = "userblocked" AND JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(e.meta,'$.reason') contains 'spam_report',1,0)) as spam_reported
```

but the syntax doesn't work for distinct counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you hoist the conditions you want to find and turn them into fields in a subselect, and then count the distinct values of the fields? In other words, something like:

```
select
    ...report_columns...,
   t1.uniquesent,
   t1.uniquedelivered,
from [main table]
left join (
  select 
    language,
    exact_count_distinct(sent) as uniquesent,
    exact_count_distinct(users_delivered) as uniquedelivered,         
  from (
    select 
      language,
      if (country=1 and event='sent', e.user_id, null) as sent,
      if (country=1 and event='delivered', e.user_id, null) as delivered,
    from emailevent e
  ) group by language
) as t1
```

This might get you into resources_exceeded territory if you are doing exact count distinct with too many distinct values. Note that if you use count distinct with a bucket count, you'll get the exact count up to the bucket count. Most of the time people care about the exact number if it is small, but it is ok if it is approximate once it gets large.

Comment: It's not clean to us when we get resources exceeded. I already posted tickets about some related to this one to the issue tracker, but no response from there. Maybe check it. User id is pretty much distinct, think 25M unique entries which I consider still small for BQ.

Answer (score 0):

For the chunk that you posted you could do something like this to reduce the number of joins.

```
select
    ...report_columns...,
   SUM(IF(event='sent', unique_event, 0)) as uniqusent
   SUM(IF(event='delivered', unique_event, 0)) as uniquedelivered
from [main table]
left join (
  select
    event,
    language,
    exact_count_distinct(e.user_id) as uniqueevent
   from emailevent e
    where country=1 and event in ('sent', 'delivered')
   group by event, language
) as sent
```